# Write a vector v in a basis given a set

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I am trying to write the vector $v = (2,3)$ in the basis outlined by the set $\{(−1, 1),(3, −5)\}$.
I figured that I would take the inverse of the set matrix, and multiply it to v. However, this does not seem to be the solution. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your steps?  In particular, what you mean by “the set matrix.”

Comment: I take a 2x2 matrix, with (-1,1) on the top row, and (3,-5) on the bottom. I imagine the way to go about this problem is to multiply the matrix by some variables, a and b, to produce v = (2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $v_1=(-1,1)$ , $v_2=(3,-5)$ and the vector of coefficients as $(a,b)$. Hence you must have $$v=(a,b)\cdot \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}$$which leads to $$v\cdot \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=(a,b)$$

Comment: Once I have my a and b values, how to I apply these to v to form the basis?

Comment: After having $a$ and $b$ at hand, you can write $$v=a\cdot (-1,1)+b\cdot (3,-5)$$

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help.

Comment: My pleasure${}{}{}{}$.